# Laravel Mix not transpiling vendor.js to es5

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, laravel-mix

Laravel Mix does not seem to transpile vendor.js and manifest.js to ES5. It fails on iPhone Safari and IE 11.

IE DevTools shows these errors:

[image: IE error]

And it appears that it still has ES6 features:

[image: es6]

The other files seem to transpile such as `app.js` and the chunks.

Here's my webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

let options = {
  processCssUrls: false,
}

let config = {
  output: {
    chunkFilename: 'assets/js/chunks/[name].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  }
}

if (mix.inProduction()) {
  config.output.chunkFilename = 'assets/js/chunks/[name].[chunkhash].js'
}

mix
  .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/assets/js')

  .sass('resources/assets/sass/web.scss', 'public/assets/css')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/fonts.scss', 'public/assets/css')

  .copy('resources/assets/img', 'public/assets/img')
  .copy('node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts','public/assets/webfonts')

  .extract([
      // Libraries...
  ])

  .disableNotifications()
  .webpackConfig(config)
  .options(options)
  .sourceMaps()

if (mix.inProduction()) {
  mix.version()
}
```

And my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

I tried the following:

1. Install `babel-preset-es2015` and add `es2015` to my `.babelrc` presets.
2. Add `.babel('[...]/vendor.js', '[...]/vendor.es5.js')` to my webpack.mix.js

How can I get the vendor.js and manifest.js file to transpile to ES5? Or at least get it working with IE 11 and iPhone Safari.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @mike.bronner I found that query-string is causing the issue. I used query-string-es5 which transpiles properly for the meantime. https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1434#issuecomment-471469511

Answer (score 1):

After some research it became clear that Laravel Mix 4.x does not transpile included packages. To achieve this, add the following to your `webpack.mix.js` file, prior to your mix commands:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(bower_components)/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: Config.babel()
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

This overrides the default configuration, which excludes `node_modules` from bring transpiled.

Comment: **Too bad this does not overrdie anything**, at least not since Laravel-Mix `^5.0.1`, it will merge simply because it can (and duplicates the laravel-mix's default, which already calls `babel-loader`, and repeated calls should do nothing).